# SQL Server analysis server 2014 error processing cube

Tags: sql-server

When trying to process a cube I keep getting the error :  "A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'SR Data Warehouse'". The thing is I do not know where to find the DataSourceID in SQL server Management studio. It appears that this is a no longer valid DataSourceID but I do not know where to change the DataSourceID for processing cubes within SQL Server Management studio. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to Analysis services server type.
2. Expand the database folder, open the Data Source folder under the database name, right-click a data source in Object Explorer and select Properties.

For more info see [Set Data Source Properties (SSAS Multidimensional)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189027.aspx)